# How to get a particaular link using python requests?

Tags: python-3.x, url, python-requests

I have the below code in python:

```
import requests
#specific gtrends for Mcdonalds
#the referred output is https://www.google.com/trends/explore?gprop=news&q=%2Fm%2F07gyp7
search_params = {'gprop' : "news", 'q' : "%2Fm%2F07gyp7" }
gtrend_resp = requests.get("https://www.google.com/trends/explore", params = search_params)
print(gtrend_resp.url)
```

How can i include `%2` in the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Unquote* it first:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.unquote("%2Fm%2F07gyp7")
'/m/07gyp7'
```

Then, the following code:

```
search_params = {'gprop' : "news", 'q' : "/m/07gyp7" }
gtrend_resp = requests.get("https://www.google.com/trends/explore", params = search_params)
print(gtrend_resp.url)
```

would produce the desired url:

```
https://www.google.com/trends/explore?gprop=news&q=%2Fm%2F07gyp7
```

Comment: thank you! it worked but for some reasons. the first try gave me this result https://www.google.com/trends/explore?q=%2Fm%2F07gyp7&gprop=news though i have the same ordering

Comment: @pythonnovice sure, you mean the ordering of query parameters is different? This is okay and expected, the ordering is actually not preserved and it should not matter.

Comment: Oh, did not know that. thank you very much. So as long as the keys and corresponding values are in their respective matches. I am using python 3.5, it gets, urllib has no attribute  unquote.

Comment: i use this one. Answers my comment ^ `from urllib.parse import unquote`